# Adding more than 4 list items overwrites older list items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating an app where you can create multiple kitchen timers. I can add an new timer and it will appear in a ListView. When I create 4 timers there is no problem, they all appear and work. When I add a 5th timer it creates a new list item but updates the content of the 4th item, not the content of the 5th item. When I create a 6th item it creates a new item in the listview, it updates the content of the 6th item but when I scroll up it also changes the content of the first item to the content of the 6th item.

Here is the code of the getView of my ArrayAdapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    mKitchenTimer = null;

    View view;
    KitchenTimerViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_kitchentimer, parent, false);
        holder = new KitchenTimerViewHolder();
        holder.kitchenTimerDuration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kitchen_timer_duration);
        holder.kitchenTimerTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kitchen_timer_title);
        holder.pauseKitchenTimer = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pause_kitchen_timer);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (KitchenTimerViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    mKitchenTimer = KitchenTimerList.get(position);

    if(!mKitchenTimer.isRunning() && !mKitchenTimer.isEnded()) {
        holder.kitchenTimerTitle.setText(mKitchenTimer.getName());
        mKitchenTimer.position = position;
        mKitchenTimer.setViewHolder(holder);
        mKitchenTimer.run();
        KitchenTimerObserver kitchenTimerObserver = new KitchenTimerObserver(mKitchenTimer);
        mKitchenTimer.addObserver(kitchenTimerObserver);
    }

    holder.pauseKitchenTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mKitchenTimer.togglePause();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```